# Stieltjes measure continuous in $x$ iff

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F_\mu$ be defined in the following way, where $\mu$ is a measure defined on the Borel $\sigma-$algebra of the reals, 
\begin{equation}
F_\mu(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\mu([0,x)) &\mbox{if } x>0\\
0 &\mbox{if } x=0\\
-\mu([x,0)) &\mbox{if } x<0\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I showed the function is left continuous and increasing, I still need to show it is continuous in $x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu(\{x\})=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $\mu$ is a finite positive measure. You have already shown that $F_\mu$ is left-continuous, so it suffices to prove that $\mu(\left \{ x \right \})=0\Leftrightarrow F_\mu(x^{+})=F_\mu(x)$.

Fix $x\in \mathbb R.$ Then, for $y>x,$

$\tag 1\mu ([x,y))=F_\mu(y)-F_\mu(x).$

Now, $F_{\mu}$ is bounded and nondecreasing, so $\lim_{t\to x^{+}}F_{\mu}(t)=\inf_{t>x}F_{\mu}(t)$ so if we let $(a_n)$ be an arbitrary sequence deceasing to $x$, then $[x,a_{n+1})\subseteq [x,a_n)$ and $ \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} [x,a_n)=\left \{ x \right \}$ and so, by the continuity of the measure $\mu ([x,a_n))\to \mu(\left \{ x \right \})$ as $n\to \infty.$

Therefore, from $(1)$ we have $\mu(\left \{ x \right \})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu ([x,a_n))=F_\mu(x^{+})-F_\mu(x).$ The result follows.

Comment: Why is $F_{\mu}$ bounded? Also, in order to conclude continuity of the measure $\mu([x, a_n)) \to \mu(\{x\})$ you need that $\mu([x, a_n)) < \infty$ for some $n$. But is that necessarily true? What if $\mu$ is counting measure, for example?

Comment: @Bungo:  I assumed at the beginning that $\mu$ was finite, which I presume the OP meant to include in the hypotheses. Otherwise, the result is not necessarily true.

Comment: OK, that seems reasonable. I agree that the result doesn't appear to be true without that hypothesis.

Comment: Yes the measure is bounded, sorry for not mentioning that